# FFMPEG change fps of audio and subtitles and merge 2 files

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

I have 30 mkv files which have multiple audio streams and multiple subtitles.

For each file I am trying to: extract the dutch audio and subtitles from that file (25fps)
And merge it with another mkv file (23.976216fps)

With this command it seems like I extract the dutch audio and subtitles into a mkv:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 23.976216 -i "S01E01 - Example.mkv" -c copy -map 0:m:language:dut S01E01.mkv
```

But it does not adjust the fps from 25 to 23.976216.
I think I am going to use mkvmerge to merge the two mkv's, but they need to be the same framerate
Anyone knows how I could make this work? Thanks! :)

Comment: mkvmerge has also framerate changing thing.

Comment: @ZavenZareyan I think thats only for video (maybe subtitles) but not audio

Answer (score 0):

The frame rate of the video has nothing to do with the frame rate of audio. They are totally independent. In fact there is really no such thing as audio frame rate (well, there is, but that’s a byproduct of the codecs). If you are changing the video frame rate by dropping frames, you are not changing the videos duration, hence you should not change the audios duration. If you are slowing down the video, you must decode the audio, slow it down (likely with pitch correction) and re-encode it.

Comment: I changed the video from 25fps to 23.976 before and it does increase the length of the video, which is what I want. But the audio stays the length of the old framerate. "decode the audio, slow it down (likely with pitch correction) and re-encode" is this possible with FFMPEG ?

Comment: You'll want to use the atempo filter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would change the audio pitch from standard PAL to NTSC framerate (example valid if your audio track is the 2nd in list, -check with ffmpeg -i video.mkv and see-)

ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vn -map 0:1 -filter:a atempo=0.95904 -y slowed-down-audio-to-23.976-fps.ac3

(23976/25000 = 0.95904 so this is the converted frame rate needed for NTSC films)

Conversely, you can figure out how to speed up NTSC standard frame rate audio to the PAL system (1.0427094).

This trick works, for example, should you want to add a better quality audio track obtained from a different source.